# I had Vs I have

Tags: difference

What do I call if there is a meeting at 10 am and current time is 10:10 am. I was late for the meeting, which is still in progress.

> I have a meeting at 10 am.

Or

> I had a meeting at 10 am.

Comment: I was late for the meeting and I need to convey it to one of my colleagues. That meeting is still in progress.

Comment: If that's the case, then better to say something like "I was supposed to attend the meeting which started at 10am"

Comment: Yup Billy that's absolutely correct, but at that point my colleague said it should be 'I have a call at 10 am' instead of 'I had a call at 10 am', as call is in progress.

Comment: But I believe if we are taking a reference point of time which has passed, in my case call/meeting was at 10 am but that time has passed and it 10:05 am. Then it should be 'I had a call at 10 am' doesn't matter if call is still in progress or not. Please clarify.

Comment: @Naranjan, What I am trying to say is that neither of your examples would work in the case of an ongoing meeting which you were late for.  I will answer now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the meeting has finished, then it is past tense:

> I had a meeting at 10am, but it only lasted 5 minutes, so now I'm free.

On the other hand if the meeting has been delayed then you need to talk about your expectation, or the time that the meeting was due. Two examples, of what you might say to a secretary in this case.

> I was expecting the meeting at 10am, but it's already 10 past and no one is here. Is there a problem?

-

> Sorry I'm late. I was due to have a meeting at 10am, but I was stuck in traffic. Can I go right in?

Comment: "I was due to have a meeting at 10 am", Can this be written as, "I was supposed to have a meeting at 10 am?"

Answer (score 1):

I don't think either of these examples would work in the particular scenario you describe.

- The example using "had" infers the meeting is over.  It's an example of the
  simple past tense.
- The example using "have" infers the meeting is yet to happen.  This is the use
  of the simple present for future events. See
  [here](https://www.ef.co.uk/english-resources/english-grammar/simple-present-future-events/) for more information on this usage.

To express what you want to say, I'd suggest something like this instead:

- *I was supposed to attend the meeting which started at 10am.*
- *I am late for the 10am meeting*